# Is this definition of commutativity correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Everywhere I see commutativity defined somewhat like this:

> A binary operator $*$ is *commutative* in $S$, if for any $x, y \in S$, the following property holds: $x*y=y*x$.

That definition is, of course, intuitive, and the reason why commutativity is defined that way in most texts need not be explained. However, I'm wondering if the following definition is correct/equivalent:

> Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the set of all subsets of $S$ of size $2$. The binary operator $*: \mathcal{T}\to S$ is *commutative*.

***Edit:*** I just realized that this definition fails to capture the fact that commutativity works if the two operands are equal... which can't be represented as a function from a set of size 2. Is there a way to modify my definition to make it work?

***Edit 2:*** One solution I'm thinking of is dropping the requirement that the operator be binary, and just define the commutative operator as $*:\mathcal{R}\to S$, where $\mathcal{R}$ is the set of *all* subsets of $S$. And then specializing the definition to a binary operator if it's acting on subsets of size $\leq 2$.

**BONUS QUESTION:** Can you define associativity in a similar way? That is, as a specific type of function?

Comment: Let $\cal T$ be the set of all [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) from $S$ of size $2$. The binary operator $*:\cal T\to S$ is commutative.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit peculiar to use the term "binary operator" for an operation whose domain is not the product of some set with itself.

Here's one way to arrange things: First, note that for any $S$ there's a natural map $$\pi : S \times S \to \mathcal (S \times S) / \sim,$$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $S \times S$ defined by declaring $(s, t) \sim (t, s)$ for all $s, t \in S$. Then, a binary operation $\ast : S \times S \to S$ is *commutative* iff it descends via $\pi$ to a map $$\tilde\ast : \mathcal (S \times S) / \sim \to S ,$$ that is, if there is a (necessarily unique) map $\tilde\ast: \mathcal (S \times S) / \sim \to S$ such that $$\ast = \tilde\ast \circ \pi .$$

**Remark** We can identify $(S \times S) / \sim$ with the set of all multisets of elements of $S$ with exactly $2$ elements.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks for the answer. But why is it peculiar to use binary operation in that way? That just means that the term binary operation has an established specific usage/meaning, but intuition says that that definition is equally good. $c=a*b$, after all, can just be a representation of $c=f(\{a,b\})$, can't it? Plus, this form is much more easily generalizable into operators having more than two operands, even if trinary operators and above don't seem to be used as much.

Comment: An $n$-ary operation is usually a map $\underbrace{S \times \cdots \times S}_n \to S$, and it might confuse a reader used to the usual definition if they see it used another way. Also, typically a definition would say that an object $X$ has a property $Y$ if (and only if) $X$ satisfies some condition.

Comment: In any case, we can only write $a \ast b = f(\{a, b\})$ (where $\{a, b\}$ is a multiset) for some function $f$ *if* $\ast$ is commutative---that's just what the modification I proposed in my answer means.